# MYSQL order according to where clause matching

Tags: mysql, sql

MYSQL:

```
SELECT `item`.* 
FROM   `item` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_category` 
              ON `item_category`.`Item` = `item`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_sub_category` 
              ON `item_sub_category`.`Item` = `item`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `cart` 
              ON `cart`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
                 AND `cart`.`user` = 3 
       LEFT JOIN `user_users` 
              ON `user_users`.`id` = 3 
WHERE  `cart`.`item` IS NULL 
       AND `item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN( '65', '66', '67', '68' ) 
        OR `item_category`.`category` IN( '35', '36' ) 
GROUP  BY `item`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `item`.`id` DESC, 
          `item`.`feature` DESC 
LIMIT  4
```

As you can see there is OR in where condition. I want to give priority to the row where both conditions are true. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Your query/schema has several problems.  First, you are using `GROUP BY`, but you are not aggregating anything.  This doesn't make much sense, and implies that either you omitted an aggregate, or that `GROUP BY` should be dropped entirely.  Also, you are joining every table to `item` using the `id` column.  This also seems suspicious.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Query is incomplete I will use a group_concat function that's why I used Group By.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes you are correct I have updated my query let's look at now.

Comment: NB: I suspect you want `\`cart\`.\`item\` IS NULL` to always be true for the returned rows, but that currently is not guaranteed. `AND ` has precedence over `OR`.

Comment: @trincot Yes I want to use OR instead of AND if both are true then give priority. According to that result select 4 rows.

Comment: I don't think you got the point I wanted  to raise: you currently could get records that have `cart.item` not equal to `NULL`. Is that intended?

Comment: @trincot `cart`.`item` must be null. Item matching with sub_category and category then give priority to this kind of item. Item matching with category  but not with sub_category  then don't give priority to this kind of item.

Comment: What trincot means is the query you have at the moment would return any item that has item_category.category in (35, 36), not caring what cart.item is.

Comment: Try to create query  using when case. The simple  example is given as below:
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN (Condition) THEN (Field name)
        ELSE (Field name)
 END 
    DESC

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
, (CASE WHEN CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

to your ORDER BY clause, where CONDITION1 and CONDITION2 are your two conditions.

Edited to show in query and to fix where AND/OR problem in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT `item`.* 
FROM   `item` 
   LEFT JOIN `item_category` 
          ON `item_category`.`Item` = `item`.`id` 
   LEFT JOIN `item_sub_category` 
          ON `item_sub_category`.`Item` = `item`.`id` 
   LEFT JOIN `cart` 
          ON `cart`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
             AND `cart`.`user` = 3 
   LEFT JOIN `user_users` 
          ON `user_users`.`id` = 3 
WHERE  `cart`.`item` IS NULL 
   AND 
   ( 
     `item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN( '65', '66', '67', '68' ) 
    OR 
      `item_category`.`category` IN( '35', '36' ) 
   )
ORDER  BY `item`.`id` DESC, 
      `item`.`feature` DESC,
      CASE WHEN `item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN( '65', '66', '67', '68' )
               AND `item_category`.`category` IN( '35', '36' )
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1 END ASC
LIMIT  4
```

What this does is sort by a virtual column which is 0 when you want to give it priority, and 1 when you do not.

Comment: Can you please write the whole query. Because I couldn't understand what you saying.